# WCF Service not streaming properly small blocks (NetTcpBinding)

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm stuck with a problem with a WCF service where smaller data blocks are not streamed without delay.

```
[OperationContract]
Stream DoTask(int taskId);
```

The Implementation looks like:

```
public IO.Stream DoTask(int taskId) {
   var stream = new MessageStream();
   Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(() => {
      RunTask(stream, taskId);
   }));
   return stream;
}
```

In the MessageStream class I implemented several functions to transfer messages, status values and documents.

The read function is always blocked until the next event via an underlying BlockingCollection and thus the stream is kept open until I have completed my task.

If the task is running, it streams various information to the client. Here you can see how the ChannelDispatcher always reads out my stream as desired immediately when new data is available.

```
18:10:28 app>>stream: [message] Connecting to vault [progress] 5
18:10:28 wcf<<stream : 23 bytes
18:10:28 app>>stream: [message] Getting metadata [progress] 10
18:10:28 wcf<<stream : 20 bytes
18:10:28 app>>stream: [message] Downloading [progress] 15
18:10:28 wcf<<stream : 15 bytes
18:10:29 app>>stream: [message] Connecting to Inventor [progress] 20
18:10:29 wcf<<stream : 26 bytes
18:10:29 app>>stream: [message] Failed. Waiting until Inventor is started [progress] 30
18:10:29 wcf<<stream : 45 bytes
18:10:32 app>>stream: [message] Loading document [progress] 35
18:10:32 wcf<<stream : 20 bytes
18:10:32 app>>stream: [message] Unwrapping model [progress] 55
18:10:32 wcf<<stream : 20 bytes
18:10:32 app>>stream: [message] Exporting DXF to file [progress] 80
18:10:32 wcf<<stream : 25 bytes
18:10:33 app>>stream: [message] Streaming [progress] 90
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 13 bytes
18:10:33 app>>stream: [file] 342938 [name] 00045135.dxf
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 256 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 4096 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 65536 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 65536 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 65536 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 65536 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 65536 bytes
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 10975 bytes
18:10:33 app>>stream: [message] Completed [progress] 100
18:10:33 wcf<<stream : 13 bytes
```

Unfortunately, the client sees this: (You can see from the timing that the first messages were all delayed.)

```
18:10:33 [message] Connecting to vault [progress] (5%)
18:10:33 [message] Getting metadata [progress] (10%)
18:10:33 [message] Downloading [progress] (15%)
18:10:33 [message] Connecting to Inventor [progress] (20%)
18:10:33 [message] Failed. Waiting until Inventor is started [progress] (30%)
18:10:33 [message] Loading document [progress] (35%)
18:10:33 [message] Unwrapping model [progress] (55%)
18:10:33 [message] Exporting DXF to file [progress] (80%)
18:10:33 [message] Streaming [progress] (90%)
18:10:33 [file] 00045135.dxf [bytes] 342938
18:10:33 [message] Completed [progress] (100%)
```

So the dispatcher seems to transfer the data only when at least 256 bytes are available or my MessageStream is completed.

Binding is  and TransferMode=Streamed.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding2" transferMode="Streamed"></binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="...Service">
        <endpoint address=""
                 binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding2"
                 contract="...IService"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8241/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Basically, I'm missing a way to perform some sort of "flush" on the service side.
If I append empty data to the messages to exceed the 256 bytes, each message is transmitted immediately.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this properly? Thanks for every hint!

Comment: So you want to delay stream of smaller data blocks?

Comment: Theobald, I want to get rid of the buffering the happens inside the WCF layer. I dont't understand why there should be no possibility to stream 1 byte.